# Remove/hide Seearch Bar in Modern Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-search, modern

How Can I remove delete/hide/get rid of a search bar in a Sharepoint List. I am not even sure why it is there. None of the regular pages have it. It only shows up in Document Libraries and List ( It is pretty useless because it doesn't return what is on the list - I do not need it and I would just rather remove it). I am okay with just disabling search on the whole Site - I just have no idea how.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I would wait for ~1 month. The search bar will move into the suitenav top and center. In general, modifying the DOM like you want to is not supported and will break in the future.